# "this" function is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table having many *td*.   When I click the button I want some html elements inside a *td*. How can I solve this function using "this"?

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function clickMe(e) {
                $(this).html ("this is hai")
            });
        });
```

```css
 table td { 
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
   height:17px;
  /*max-height:10px;*/

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid;width:10%;height:100px;margin-top:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td id="container"onclick="clickMe(this)"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="container"  > clickme</button>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: **1.** ID should be unique. **2.** `clickMe` is _local_ to `ready()`. **3.** There should be no space in `.html (`

Comment: also once you change you id to a class (which would be preferable), then you can use in in jquery $('.container').on('click',function clickMe(e) { ... }); and remove the onclick from html.

Comment: please give me a perfect script using this

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38010839/6338065) @manupadmanabhan

Comment: already fixed it @manupadmanabhan ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to resuse the clickMe function? Then you should place it globally and remove the parameter, which isn't necessary.

Btw: the duplication of the ids is bad practice, but it'll still work:

edit: You should use `onclick="clickMe.call(this)"` to bind the current element to `this` in the clickMe function.

```js
function clickMe() {
  $(this).html ("this is hai")
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(clickMe);
});
```

```css
table td { 
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
   height:17px;
  /*max-height:10px;*/

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid;width:10%;height:100px;margin-top:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td id="container" onclick="clickMe.call(this)"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="container"  > clickme</button>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change to :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <table id="table_id">
            <tr>
              <td>Td</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
       </table>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#table_id td").on("click",function(){
                  $(this).html("this is hai");
            })
        })        
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#table_id td").on("click", function(){
    $(this).html("this is hai");
  });
});
```

```css
#table_id td { 
     border: 1px solid;
     border-color: lightgray;
     overflow:hidden;
     height:17px;
}

#table_id{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="table_id">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not really know what you want, is it like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the content to be placed in the container OR the  just try this:

`//it is unclear to me _what you exactly want_ if _this_ is <b>not</b> what you want. Give  me a comment on _what is not correct_ and i'll try to edit goodluck!`

```js
$('#my_button').on('click', function(){
$('#place_here').html ("this is hai")

});
```

```css
 table td { 
     border: 1px solid;
    border-color: lightgray;
    overflow:hidden;
   height:17px;
  /*max-height:10px;*/

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid;width:10%;height:100px;margin-top:50px;">
        <tr>
            <td id="container"></td>
          <td id="place_here"></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="my_button"> clickme</button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) works, your code doesn't make sense at all. Remember the ID should be unique you're better of using class if you need to implement it on a page multiple times. I created a demo so you could understand how should a script work.

I made your button that when clicked will populate the 3 td's, notice i reference the TD with their ID on jQuery button click event. After populating the TD you'll be able to click each TDs and it will output its HTML content. See the script below.

```js
       $(document).ready(function () {
                $("button").click(function(e) {
                   $("#td1").html ("this is hai displayed at td1");
                    $("#td2").html ("this is hai displayed at td2");
                   $("#td3").html ("this is hai displayed at td3");
                });
         
               window.clickMe = function (data){
                 alert(jQuery(data).html());
               }
            });
```

```css
     table td { 
         border: 1px solid;
        border-color: lightgray;
        overflow:hidden;
       height:17px;
      /*max-height:10px;*/

    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <html>
      <body>
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid;width:10%;height:100px;margin-top:50px;" >
            <tr>
                <td id="td1" onclick="clickMe(this)"></td>
              <td id="td2" onclick="clickMe(this)"></td>
              <td id="td3" onclick="clickMe(this)"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button id="container"  > clickme</button>
      </body>
        </html>
```